# How would I calculate the better performance based on percentages?

Tags: statistics

I've been looking at how the characteristics of web content relate to the number of views it receives.

I looked at the percentage of content with that characteristic, and then the percentage of views on that content.

For example -

16% of pages are in format X - but receive 12% of pageviews

1% of pages are in format Y - but receive 2% of pageviews

...and so on.

So in simple terms we can see that Y is better than X, despite having a lower number of pageviews overall. But I'm struggling with best way to present that - can I say that Y is _% better than X and how would I make that calculation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate which is better, simply divide the number of pages of type X by the number of views of those pages.  This results in views per page by format.

In your example, assume you have 100 pages so 16 are format X and 1 is format Y, and you have 100 page views so 12 are of format X and 2 are of format Y.  Then you will have $$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{format} & \text{views per page} \\ \hline X & 0.750 \\ Y & 2.000\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the ratio of the fraction of views to the fraciton of pages is a "share multiplier", which indicates the degree to which it recieves views out of proporation to its share (assuming there are no actual differences in the propensity to view a page).

Then, you would get 0.75 for X and 2 for Y, indicating that Y-format is more popular than X's format.